# Submitting a textfield on 'Enter' or if something change with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to start an Ajax action with JQuery. For this I have the following code, which also works:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('blur', '.priceConference', function(){  

                       var id = $(this).data("id2");  
                       var priceConference = $(this).text();  
                       edit_data(id,priceConference, "priceConference"); 

            });
```

**HTML:**

```
<td class="priceConference" data-id2="'.$row["idBookingConference"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["priceConference"].' €</td>
```

However, I don´t want to start the edit_data () function when there is no focus on the field ('blur') . But I want to start the dunction if the content was really changed or when the user enter the key "Enter".

I have tested it with the following code, but it does not work. What can it be?

**New jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".priceConference").change(function(){
                    var id = $(this).data("id2");  
                    var priceConference = $(this).text();  
                    edit_data(id,priceConference, "priceConference"); 
                });
            });
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Should `contenteditable>` not be `contenteditable=` with an `=` ?

Comment: The contenteditable attribute specifies whether the content of an element is editable or not. But it is not important if you write contenteditable="true" or only <td [...] contenteditable>. Both of them works fine. :)

Comment: [contenteditable MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) This attribute is an enumerated one and not a Boolean one. This means that the explicit usage of one of the values true, false or the empty string is mandatory and that a shorthand like `<label contenteditable>Example Label</label>` is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `contenteditable` elements, use the `keydown` event.  The `change` event does nothing. To only call the function if the value was really changed, I have added the original value onto the data of the element which is checked before sending the Ajax.

```js
$('td').on('keydown', function(e) { // For capturing the Enter key
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && $(this).text() !== $(this).data('originalValue')) {
    $(this).data('originalValue', $(this).text());
    e.preventDefault(); // no newline
    console.log('Call Ajax');
  }
}).on('focusin', function(e) { // Set value on click
  $(this).data('originalValue', $(this).text());
}).on('focusout', function(e) { // Check if value changed on click away
  if ($(this).text() !== $(this).data('originalValue'))
    console.log('Call Ajax');
});
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can handle enter with below code

```
   <td onKeyPress='return submitEnter(event)' ></td>   

        function submitEnter(e) {
               if((e && e.keyCode == 13) || e == 0) {
                 // enter handled here
               }
            }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn´t work. The system create a newline and not a click event.